# MongoDB ssl .pem file in connection string

Tags: mongodb, ssl, pem

I have a mongodb server v 3.2 configured to use ssl for client connections, with a custom-generated certificate.
I can connect to the server using mongo.exe with the following format:

> C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe myhost:27017/mydb --sslPEMKeyFile
>   C:\etc\ssl\mongodb.pem --ssl --username myuser --password mypassword
>   --sslAllowInvalidCertificates

Is it possible to write an equal  mongodb connection string (mongodb://....)?
According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), there is the only ssl parameter, that seems to be not enough.

Comment: Just use ```--ssl``` and ```--sslAllowInvalidCertificates```, see if it works

Comment: Thank it helps, however valid key is sslAllowInvalidCertificate (without s).

Comment: Hmm, I think [it does](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#mongo-shell-ssl-configuration) have an `s`? (well at least since v3.2.6 anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to connect to mongo.exe with the parameter like below:

> "mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myhost:27017/mydb?ssl=true&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&sslPEMKeyFile=C:/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem"

Comment: See documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-options (tlsCertificateKeyFile)

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
mongo --host server --ssl --sslCAFile C:\Path\mongodb-server.pem 
--sslPEMKeyFile C:\Path\mongodb-client.pem --sslPEMKeyPassword 
password -u user -p  --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question completely.  The OP asks `"Is it possible to write an equal mongodb connection string (mongodb://....)?"`